# Do form validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form in which I have a field where the user enters their phone number and we force them to start with +34 followed by 9 digits (12 digits in total are what that field should have), but then when I change at +31 for example I pick it up as if it were +34, this is using a

```
<input type="text">
```

This is a variable

```
let phone2 = phone.length
```

This is the contidion I am using in Javascript

```
if (phone != '+34' & phone2 < 12) {
        evt.preventDefault ();
        alert ('The phone number must start with +34 and have at least 12 digits');
        
      }
```

If anyone can help me

Comment: What's the value of **phone** ? Use the **substring()** mehtod to check the first 3 characters of **phone** instead of checking the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Note that `onblur` means that the test function will fire when the input field loses focus. So, to run the test, type something and then click outside the input field.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function test() {
  const phone = $('input').value;
  if (phone.substr(0, 3) !== '+34' || phone.length < 12) {
    alert('The phone number must start with +34 and have at least 12 digits');
  } else {
    alert('good job');
  }
}
```

```html
<input onblur="test()" placeholder="Phone (must begin with +34)" />
```

Comment: should be && condition or?

Comment: but when I put +31 for example, he takes it as if it were +34